# Django 1.11: totally weird HTML-escape problem

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm moving a codebase to Django 1.11, and some of my widgets now display HTML as if they are being HTML-escaped:

```
<h2>Hello from Foo</h2>
```

I've been through the docs about `autoescape` and `safe`, with no joy.  So I thought I would go back to basics of templates.  This is literally the only text in my template file:

```
<h2>Hello from Foo</h2>
```

And yet the browser renders the  tag as ascii text, and not as a formatting command to the browser.[image]

How can this be happening?  There is no variable-expansion or autoescape anywhere near this, and no simple_tag that now defaults to autoescape.  But some agent is applying an HTML-escape to this code.

I'm baffled.

Comment: Can you show the entirety of the template file?

Comment: What is your template configuration in `settings.py`?

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem that sounds almost exactly like yours.

Had a templatetag which, after the migration to django 1.11, started returning HTML-escaped content.

Tried replicating the problem on the previous version of Django I had which was 1.8 and had no luck.

In the end, I added the `mark_safe` from `django.utils.safestring` to the return statement and it fixed my problem. Also tried all variants of adding the `safe`, `escape` filters and `autoescape` tags, but had no luck with that.

EDIT: just found out about this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates

Looks like since Django 1.10 the `autoescape` options was introduced and it defaults to `True` for `DjangoTemplates`. Looks like this could be what causes the described problems.